# Sort an array and put it in a linked list

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, linked-list

I have an algorithm in pseudocode which takes an unsorted array as input and puts it sorted in a linked list. I don't understand very well how it works. Maybe there's an error in it. I've been trying for more than an hour to understand how does it work but I'm stuck at some point. I'll explain as much as I understand. Anyone who knows how it works is pleased to help.

```
ORDER(A)
head [L1] = create();    //Null List is created.
key[head[L1]] = A[1];    //First element of the array is put as the first in list.

for i=2 to length(A);
    x = create();        // create a node for every element of the array
    key[x] = A[i];       // put A[i] as key in the node.
    p1 = head[L1];       // make p1 head of the list.
    if key[p1] > A[i];       //compare A[i] with the head
       insert_head(x);      // if smaller put it in the beggining and make it head
    while key[next[p1]] < A[i] AND next[p1] =/= nil  // This part I don't understand 
       if next[p1] == nil                               //very well.
          next[p1] = x
          next[x] = nil
       else
          next[x] = next[p1]
          next[p1] = x;
```

Comment: `Sort an array and put it in a linked list` or `take an unsorted array and put it in a sorted linked list`?

Comment: Take an unsorted array and put it in a sorted linked list.

Answer (score 3):

It's very similar to [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).

The linked-list is sorted and starts off empty, and then each element in the array is inserted into the linked-list in the correct position such that it's sorted after every insert.

For the insert, it goes through the linked-list until the element we're looking to insert is smaller than the current element in the linked-list, or we've reached the end of the linked-list, and then inserts.

I do think there might be a bug, I think the while-loop should be:

```
// here we advance the position in the linked-list
//   until we reach the end or the current element is smaller
while key[next[p1]] < A[i] AND next[p1] =/= nil
  p1 = next[p1]

// if we reached the end, next[x] won't point to anything
if next[p1] == nil                          
  next[p1] = x
  next[x] = nil
// if we didn't reach the end,
//   next[x] needs to point to anything what next[p1] was pointing to
else
  next[x] = next[p1]
  next[p1] = x;
```

Comment: This algorithm has O(n^2) it  can be proformed in O(n log-n) ordering the array with a better algorithm and then passing it to a list

Comment: @Qsebas Indeed, or passing it directly to the linked-list and ordering that in O(n log n).

Answer (score 1):

The pseudocode you have is an implementation of [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort), who has a worst case complexity of O(n^2).

Basically the while block is cycling the whole list that is keeping the sorted subset of data, when the while finds the spots where to insert, it insert it in the sorted list. If the while didn't find the spot where to insert, it insert it at the end of the list.

maybe you should consider of using [Merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) (complexity O(n log-n)) and then passing it to a list (O(n))

The total complexity for this proposal is O(n log n)

Comment: The advantage, from a learning standpoint, of all the O(n^2) algorithms (bubblesort, selection sort, insertion sort) is that they are simple and easy to implement.  Moreover, for small arrays (less than 100 elements) selection and insertion sort are typically more performant than divide-and-conquer algorithms due to their lower over head costs.  The wrong way to address a new learner's question about sorting is to focus solely on time complexity.